# vanilla js marquee with opposite direction

Tags: javascript, slider, marquee

Here is a link ``https://codepen.io/tmhrtwg/pen/Pvywx`Y` for marquee which is coded with vanilla js.
Now it goes from right to left. I need to get the opposite direction variant for this marquee.
Waiting for your help guys!

I need the opposite varaint of this `https://codepen.io/tmhrtwg/pen/PvywxY`

Comment: And how much would you like to pay?